# How to get json object array from deep nested json array?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-recyclerview, retrofit

This is my json, I wanted to get 'products' arrays object.

```
{
       "Categories":[
          {
             "id":6,
             "status":"1",
             "parent_id":"0",
             "name":"Bottom Wear",
             "name_ar":"\u0623\u0633\u0641\u0644 \u0627\u0631\u062a\u062f\u0627\u0621",
             "picture":null,
             "description":"gents bottom wear",
             "slug":"bottom-wear",
             "created_at":"2017-06-05 21:08:28",
             "updated_at":"2017-06-05 21:08:28",
             "deleted_at":null,
             "product":[
                {
                   "id":2,
                   "status":"1",
                   "name":"Pants",
                   "name_ar":"\u0628\u0646\u0637\u0644\u0648\u0646",
                   "dryclean_price":"9",
                   "washing_price":"6",
                   "press":"4",
                   "sw_dryclean_price":"9",
                   "sw_washing_price":"6",
                   "sw_press":"4",
                   "picture":null,
                   "created_at":"2017-04-19 21:32:04",
                   "updated_at":"2017-06-05 21:18:04",
                   "deleted_at":null,
                   "pivot":{
                      "category_id":"6",
                      "product_id":"2"
                   }
                },
                {
                   "id":8,
                   "status":"1",
                   "parent_id":"0",
                   "name":"Undergarments",
                   "name_ar":"\u0623\u062b\u0648\u0627\u0628 \u062a\u062d\u062a\u0627\u0646\u064a\u0629",
                   "picture":null,
                   "description":"Undergarments",
                   "slug":"undergarments",
                   "created_at":"2017-06-05 21:22:09",
                   "updated_at":"2017-06-05 21:22:09",
                   "deleted_at":null,
                   "product":[
                      {
                         "id":23,
                         "status":"1",
                         "name":"Underwear",
                         "name_ar":"\u062b\u064a\u0627\u0628 \u062f\u0627\u062e\u0644\u064a\u0629",
                         "dryclean_price":"5",
                         "washing_price":"3",
                         "press":"2",
                         "sw_dryclean_price":"5",
                         "sw_washing_price":"3",
                         "sw_press":"2",
                         "picture":null,
                         "created_at":"2017-04-19 21:35:31",
                         "updated_at":"2017-06-05 21:23:42",
                         "deleted_at":null,
                         "pivot":{
                            "category_id":"8",
                            "product_id":"23"
                         }
                      },
                      {
                         "id":34,
                         "status":"1",
                         "name":"Socks",
                         "name_ar":"\u062c\u0648\u0627\u0631\u0628",
                         "dryclean_price":"5",
                         "washing_price":"3",
                         "press":"2",
                         "sw_dryclean_price":"5",
                         "sw_washing_price":"3",
                         "sw_press":"2",
                         "picture":null,
                         "created_at":"2017-06-05 21:26:14",
                         "updated_at":"2017-06-05 21:26:14",
                         "deleted_at":null,
                         "pivot":{
                            "category_id":"8",
                            "product_id":"34"
                         }
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

I am able to save categories in my db like this.

```
  protected final String CategoryTable = "category_table";
    protected final String D_ID = "category_id";
    protected final String D_SERVER_ID = "categoryserver_id";
    protected final String D_JSON = "category_json";

 public boolean insertCategory(Category model) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        cv.put(D_SERVER_ID, model.getId());
        cv.put(D_JSON, new Gson().toJson(model));
        int res = (int) database.insert(CategoryTable, null, cv);
        database.close();
        if (res > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

  public Collection<Category> getAllCategories() {
        database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ArrayList<Category> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + CategoryTable, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Category obj = gson.fromJson(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(D_JSON)), Category.class);
                if (obj != null)
                    lst.add(obj);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return lst;
    }
```

Here is a Category Model class:

```
public class Category {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("parent_id")
    @Expose
    private String parentId;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("name_ar")
    @Expose
    private String nameAr;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("slug")
    @Expose
    private String slug;
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    @Expose
    private String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    @Expose
    private String updatedAt;
    @SerializedName("deleted_at")
    @Expose
    private Object deletedAt;
    @SerializedName("product")
    @Expose
    private List<Product> product = null;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getParentId() {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(String parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNameAr() {
        return nameAr;
    }

    public void setNameAr(String nameAr) {
        this.nameAr = nameAr;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getSlug() {
        return slug;
    }

    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(String updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    public Object getDeletedAt() {
        return deletedAt;
    }

    public void setDeletedAt(Object deletedAt) {
        this.deletedAt = deletedAt;
    }

    public List<Product> getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(List<Product> product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

}
```

I am using retrofit library to get data. Here is the method I am using to save categories array in my db.

```
@Override
    public void onSuccess(Call call, Response response, int reqCode) {
        Loading.cancel();
        ProductsResponse productsResponse = (ProductsResponse) response.body();
        for (int i = 0; i < productsResponse.getCategories().size(); i++) {
            Category obj = productsResponse.getCategories().get(i);
            categories.add(obj);
            categoriesHandler.insertCategory(obj);
            categoriesHandler.insertLabel(obj.getName());
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        loadSpinnerData();
}
```

But how can I get product jsonArray from categories. Tried a lot but not able to find a method. Your help would be appreciated. Need to get products on the bases of categories. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Ashish I am using your method:

```
 private void categorySelector(String str){
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        JSONArray mainData = (JSONArray) categoriesHandler.getAllCategories();
        ArrayList<Category> responseAsArrayList =
                gson.fromJson(mainData.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Category>>() {
                }.getType());
        for(int i =0;i<responseAsArrayList.size();i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < responseAsArrayList.get(i).getProduct().size();j++)
            {
                Category category =  responseAsArrayList.get(i);
                Product product = category.getProduct().get(j);
                products.add(product);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Can you post the Category class? The category class has to mirror the json structure.

Comment: Sow the Category class implementation

Comment: Your code should work Gson will automatically parse the product array, try to log the Json string from `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(D_JSON))` and verify that it contains a "product" JsonArray

Comment: Use gson parsing make you easy to get each and every key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1) Make your response with gson properties ..http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ will help to make gson class.

> youSource type: JSON , Annotation style: GSON And add getter setter
>   method.

Step 2) Now you have all the class with gson annotation.

Step 3) Now json

```
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
 JSONArray mainData = response.getJSONArray("Categories");
 ArrayList<YourMasterClass> responseAsArrayList = 
                      gson.fromJson(mainData.toString(), new TypeToken<List<YourMasterClass>>() {
                    }.getType());
```

Step 4) After getting all the data in arraylist now your logic will in play.

> Here i have just write assume arraylist name so please replace your gson class.

```
for(int i =0;i<responseAsArrayList.size();i++)
{
      for(int j = 0; responseAsArrayList.get(i).getProductArray().size();j++)
      {
          // Here you will get your Product object
      }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, i made pojo classes for response. I stored main json array in my db. now I m collecting those categories from db. But I want to get products from my db on the bases of my category name. Any help for that? You can getAllCategories() method in my question. Thanks for help

Comment: According to my experience with db i would like to make so easy way . I never user much keys for store data. I just make two key in db like key => Id and another Value => Whole json. So in your case  in category array have     "id":6, key so now just add as Key in db and in Value save whole object.

Comment: Now just fire a query with id like give me value ; It will return whole object as string . At that time just parse that string with Gson as i display in answer. So it will easy to get particular object and after parse that value , Now you can get any of key as you want

Comment: And further tell me how to get the products from this method on the basis of category name. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Like which category name have  "name":"Bottom Wear", you want that only product right?

Comment: Yes . Exactly. So it only returns those products that lie in category "Bottom Wear".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146135/discussion-between-ashish-and-zeeshan-sardar).

Comment: Than Just add if condition in internal for loop and break there if you get. Like

  
                Category category =  responseAsArrayList.get(i);
               if(category.getName().equalIngorecase("Bottom Wear")){
                Product product = category.getProduct().get(j);
                products.add(product); break;
                }

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray array = object.optJSONArray("Categories");  // first get your Categories array from Json Object.

 // Then iterate your categories array.
for (int i = 0; i <array.length ; i++)
    {
        JSONObject innerObject = array.getJSONObject(i);     // get inner json object from array.
        JSONArray innerArray = object.optJSONArray("product");       // then get product array from inner json object
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

1) If *created* and *updated* are String, make *deleted* a string too.

2) Assuming Person is well reflecting the json structure, and so does a class for Pivot, to get to products you can do this:

```
ArrayList<Category> categories = getAllCategories();
for(Category category : categories){
    for(Product product : category.getProduct()){
         <Do something with each product of the category >
    }
}
```

3) In Category a better name to get the product's list is getPrduct**s**() instead of getProduct().

EDIT 1

To search by product name:

The slow way:

This goes through all categories until it finds a product matching the productName. If there is more than one it returns the first one.

```
Product getProductByName(String productName){
        Product rtn = null;
        ArrayList<Category> categories = getAllCategories();
        for(Category category : categories){
            for(Product product : category.getProduct()){

                 if(product.getName().equals(productName){
                    rtn = product;
                    break;
                 }
            }
        }
        return rtn;
}
```

Different approaches you can take to search more quickly:

1) Instead of storing the json string, unwrap the different objects and put the information in different tables: categoris, products, pivot.

2) Build some kind of index where you have for each product which is record that keeps the json string, the id of the category and the id of the product. When you need a product you look it up in the index and read the specific record you need to extract the product.

3) A caching strategy that combines the slow lookup with  the indexing in a `hashmap`.

There are probably more things you can do, this is to provide some ideas.

EDIT 2

Products by category name:

```
ArrayList<Product> getProductsByCategoryName(String categoryName){
    ArrayList<Product> rtn = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Category> categories = getAllCategories();
    for(Category category : categories){
        if(category.getName().equals(categoryName){
           rtn = category.getProduct();
        }
    }
    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I m collecting categories collection from my db. But i want products on the basis on category name from getAllCategories method. How can I achieve that. You can see my getAllCategories method in my question. OR can suggest another way to get products on the basis of category name. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

json.getJSONArray("Categories").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("product")

will give you product array